# How to pass boolean parameter value in pipeline to downstream jobs?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins v2.1 with the integrated delivery pipeline feature (https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) to orchestrate two existing builds (build and deploy).

In my parameterized build I have 3 user parameters setup, which also needs to be selectable in the pipeline.

The pipeline script is as follows:

```
node: {
    stage 'build'
    build job: 'build', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'target', value: target], [$class: 'ListSubversionTagsParameterValue', name: 'release', tag: release], [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'update_composer', value: update_composer]]

    stage 'deploy'
    build job: 'deploy', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'target', value: target]]
}
```

This works correctly except for the `BooleanParameterValue`. When I build the pipeline the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue.value expects boolean but received class java.lang.String
```

How can I resolve this typecasting error?
Or even better, is there a less cumbersome way in which I can just pass ALL the pipeline parameters to the downstream job.

Comment: How am I able to use (F.e. print the value of 'target') them in my downstream job?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming

```
value: update_composer
```

was the issue, try

```
value: Boolean.valueOf(update_composer)
```

> is there a less cumbersome way in which I can just pass ALL the pipeline parameters to the downstream job

Not that I know of, at least not without using Jenkins API calls and disabling the Groovy sandbox.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll try this next monday when I'm back at work. Have a few days off now.

Comment: Your answer works for me. I even found a shorter way when reading the groovy docs. `update_composer.toBoolean()` also works.

Comment: +1 for @BramGerritsen comment - this worked for me even in the Groovy sandbox, whereas the `Boolean.valueOf` did not :)

Answer (score 57):

In addition to [Jesse Glick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12916/jesse-glick) answer, if you want to pass string parameter then use:

```
build job: 'your-job-name', 
    parameters: [
        string(name: 'passed_build_number_param', value: String.valueOf(BUILD_NUMBER)),
        string(name: 'complex_param', value: 'prefix-' + String.valueOf(BUILD_NUMBER))
    ]
```

Comment: `build job: 'deploy', parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'target', value: target)]` is the equivalient syntax for boolean parameters

Comment: this seems to work for newer Jenkins only, see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27295

Answer (score 15):

like Jesse [Jesse Glick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12916/jesse-glick) and [abguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4795964/abguy) said you can enumerate string into Boolean type:

```
Boolean.valueOf(string_variable)
```

or the opposite Boolean into string:

```
String.valueOf(boolean_variable)
```

in my case I had to to downstream Boolean parameter to another job.
So for this you will need the use the class **BooleanParameterValue** :

```
build job: 'downstream_job_name', parameters:
[
[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'parameter_name', value: false],
], wait: true
```

Comment: wondering why BooleanParameterValue is not listed in the documentation of the plugin: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#-build-%20build%20a%20job

Answer (score 13):

```
build job: 'downstream_job_name', parameters: [
    booleanParam(name: 'parameter_name', value: false)
]
```

(cf. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#-build-%20build%20a%20job)

Answer (score 8):

Jenkins "boolean" parameters are really just a shortcut for the "choice parameter" type with the choices hardcoded to the strings "true" and "false", and with a checkbox to set the string variable. But in the end, it is just that: a string variable, with nothing to do with a true boolean. That's why you need to convert the string to a boolean if you don't want to do a string comparison like:

`if (myBoolean == "true")`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this answers this question. But I was looking for something else. Highly recommend see [this 2 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_tvlaIeQUQ). If you wanted to get into more details then see [docs - Handling Parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) and this [link](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines)

And then if you have something like **blue ocean**, the choices would look something like this:

[image]

<sub>As discussed in the video, Jenkins is blue because it's using [Blue Ocean Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/blueocean/)</sub>

You define and access your variables like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "TEST", description: 'What environment?', name: 'userFlag')
    choice(choices: ['TESTING', 'STAGING', 'PRODUCTION'], description: 'Select field for target environment', name: 'DEPLOY_ENV')
    }

    stages {
        stage("foo") {
            steps {
                echo "flag: ${params.userFlag}"
                echo "flag: ${params.DEPLOY_ENV}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Automated builds will pick up the default params. But if you do it manually then you get the option to choose.

And then assign values like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not related to the question, which is regarding passing downstream parameters to a job

Answer (score 1):

Things are much easier nowadays: the builtin Snippet Generator supports the 'build' step (I don't know since when though).