# How do I get the build_number of a downstream job in a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative Jenkins pipeline, I need to start job B, get its build_number, so I can call another job later that references artifacts from that specific build.

[Return parameters/results from a job(triggered by pipeline) back to the same pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539613/return-parameters-results-from-a-jobtriggered-by-pipeline-back-to-the-same-pip/39621733#39621733) looks like it would work in the older groovy Jenkinsfiles but the new declarative syntax does not allow me to define a variable based on the "build job" step.

```
    stage ('Provision system testbed') {
        steps {
            build job: 'Build_Testbed', parameters: [
                string(name: 'TOPOLOGY', value: 'flat')
            ]
            **// How to we get the build_number from above?**
        }
    }

    stage ('System tests') {
        steps {
            sh """
                bundle exec rake spec:system || true
            """

            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'results/*.xml'])
        }
    }

    stage ('Destroy system testbed') {
        steps {
             build job: 'Destroy_Testbed', parameters: [
                string(name: 'BUILD_SELECTOR', value: '<SpecificBuildSelector plugin="copyartifact@1.38.1">  <buildNumber>**714**</buildNumber></SpecificBuildSelector>')
            ]
        }
    }
```

Of course, I'm open to completely alternative solutions, too

---

Solution:

```
    stage ('Provision system testbed') {
        steps {
            script {
                def setupResult = build job: 'Build_Testbed', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'TOPOLOGY', value: 'flat')
                ]
                def systest_build_number = setupResult.getNumber()
                // Navigate to jenkins > Manage jenkins > In-process Script Approval
                // staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String java.lang.Object
                env['setup_build_number'] = setupResult.getNumber()
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('System tests') {
        steps {
            sh """
                bundle exec rake spec:system || true
            """

            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'results/*.xml'])
        }
    }

    stage ('Destroy system testbed') {
        steps {
             build job: 'Destroy_Testbed', parameters: [
                string(name: 'BUILD_SELECTOR', value: '<SpecificBuildSelector plugin="copyartifact@1.38.1">  <buildNumber>${env.setup_build_number}</buildNumber></SpecificBuildSelector>')
            ]
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** Requires approval of the script in my Jenkins server at                     Jenkins > Manage jenkins > In-process Script Approval

```
staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> looks like it would work in the older groovy Jenkinsfiles

you can use the `script` step to enclose a block of code, and, inside this block, declarative pipelines basically act like scripted, so you can still use the technique described in the answer you referenced.

welcome to stackoverflow. i hope you enjoy yourself here.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and found that instead of using the following avoids 'Requires approval of the script in my Jenkins server at Jenkins > Manage jenkins > In-process Script Approval'.

Instead of:
env['setup_build_number'] = setupResult.getNumber() (from code mentioned in Solution above)

Use this:
env.setup_build_number = setupResult.getNumber()