# Jenkins how to email the status of a view which contains multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to email the status of a view in Jenkins.
Basically i have multiple jobs around 50 running.i know we can specially go to each job & trigger a mail status if it passes or fails but i want to email the status of all 50 jobs in one go.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My solution to achieve this would be starting a *master* job that would trigger the 50 other jobs and get their output.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656390/7323888) on how to trigger another job in pipeline and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42267268/7323888) on how to get the result from the trigger job.

Once you get the triggering working you can mail the result to yourself using emailext plugin.