# Pipeline multiple jenkins jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I am very new to Jenkins.

There are multiple jobs already configured in Jenkins, As of now we are running all the jobs manually one after the other. I want to make it a single job by pipeline plugin, So that manual effort is reduced.

I had gone through the links, It states we should have JenkinsFile in our repository it basically contains command's to execute the different tasks.

But if i am configuring it in JenkinsFile how can give the existing job names ?

Is it the only way to do a pipeline or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Ex : I have three jobs

1. build-dev-code
2. test-dev-code
3. deploy-stage

I would like to pipeline all the three jobs,

```
  deploy-stage-ci
```

So that it contains all the 3 above mentioned jobs.

Comment: If you use a pipeline you will have a single *job* with multiple *stages*. You can use the same names for those stages as you used for the jobs they replace, if you like.

Comment: Could you give any example

Comment: If you Google "jenkinsfile pipeline" there are plenty out there already!

Comment: Is there any other way? If i don't want to include JenkinsFile

Comment: Given that it's now the standard way of doing things, why don't you want to include a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: I want to make use of the jenkins jobs which are already existing... Is it possible to include them in JenkinsFile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131502/discussion-between-jay-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 13):

You don't always need a Jenkinsfile to use Pipeline. In your Pipeline job, choose "Pipeline Script" from the dropdown to get a script editor.
[image: Pipeline script editor]

To build your three jobs sequentially, in a pipeline, use the following script (using names from your example). It simply wraps each job in a stage and builds it. This will also give you a pretty stage view while it runs your jobs:

```
stage('Build') {
  build 'build-dev-code'
}
stage('Test') {
  build 'test-dev-code'
}
stage('Deploy') {
  build 'deploy-stage'
}
```

Comment: Exactly, the same way i tried and it is working.. One more thing i would like to know is can we have the parameters passed for each job once pipeline is started??

Comment: @Jay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025175/pipeline-pass-parameters-to-downstream-jobs