# Pass variables across Jenkins Multi-Branch Declarative Pipeline Projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have project A and project B.  I would like to pass parameters (like the BranchName and ArtifactoryID) from project A to project B.   Both are multi-branch pipelines using a Declarative Script Jenkinsfile.

When I use the Snippet Generator it tells me the project "is not parameterized".  When looking at the config of the multi-branch pipeline, I don't see a way to parameterize it.  What am I missing?  (see attached)

[image]

[image]

A google result shows this, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to pass params between multi-branch pipelines:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32780

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out.  I leveraged an answer from a comment here:  [Pipeline pass parameters to downstream jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025175/pipeline-pass-parameters-to-downstream-jobs)

For a detailed explanation using my example shown above, my **Project A** jenkinsfile would have the following before the stages:

```
  parameters
  {
    string(name: 'BRANCH_PASSED_OVER', defaultValue: '${env.BRANCH_NAME}', description: 'pass branch value')
    string(name: 'PERSON2', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
  }
```

...and the following for the build step phase

```
  stage('Build downstream')
  {
    steps
    {
    build job: 'BUILD/CMTest2/' + env.BRANCH_NAME.replaceAll("/", "%2F"), wait: false, parameters: [string(name: 'PERSON2', value: params.PERSON2), string(name: 'PASS_BRANCH_NAME', value: env.BRANCH_NAME)]
    }
  }
```

In **Project B** then in my jenkinsfile I could call the param like so:

```
  stage('Collect Info')
  {
    steps
    {
      echo "Hello ${params.PERSON2}"
      echo "PASS_BRANCH_NAME: ${params.PASS_BRANCH_NAME}"
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you calling the build via rest? I'm receiving either a 500 or 404 HTTP error when calling POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/job/projectname/job/branchname/buildWithParameters?PARAM_NAME=value